# Знаком ли кто с kendryte k210?

Tags: embedded, электроника, iot

Интересуюсь вопросом, работал ли кто с **kendryte k210** (конкретно с отладочной платой **sipeed maix one dock** на модуле **m1w**)? Может кто-то нашел более подробную документацию чем datasheet и официальные примеры из SDK на GitHub? И может кто помочь разобраться с **fpioa** и **gpiohs**?

Буду очень благодарен!